# Have keyboard already presented on view on viewDidAppear?

Tags: ios, uitextview, uipageviewcontroller, uikeyboard

I have a `UIPageViewController` initialized with three controllers. When I swipe to the right, I am presenting a `UIView` which has a `UITextView` which becomes a firstResponder. What I am trying to achieve is to have the keyboard already appearing when the user swipes to the right, and when they swipe away to hide the keyboard within its view. It seems the keyboard is added onto the window? Facebook seems to achieve this when posting a new post, which the keyboard seems to be loaded before the view appears?

I was able to get the keyboard to show without animating the keyboard when the `becomeFirstResponder` is invoked on my UITextView. But there seems to be a delay on when the keyboard appears.

```
self.composeView.bodyTextView.inputAccessoryView = [UIView new];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(willShowKeyboard:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(didShowKeyboard:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Are you put the `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` in the `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I added becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad..it seems to work but my problem is that the keyboard hides and then is re-shown

Comment: what you did in `willShowKeyboard:` and `didShowKeyboard`?

Comment: [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];

Comment: did you call the becomeFirstResponder twice?

Answer (score 1):

It seem that show the view controller and pop up the keyboard at the same time will cause some delay.
So my suggestion is to let the keyboard show up a little later. You can do that either by  put the `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` in the `viewDidAppear:` or subclassing the UITextField to override the `didMoveToSuperview` (put `[self becomeFirstResponder]` on it).

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.textNote becomeFirstResponder];
} did the work for me. Thanks